# Mapshaper CLI: Trying to filter on iso_a2

Tags: mapshaper

I'm new to Mapshaper and I tried to find a good tutorial, but found none that answered my questions.

- I'm using mapshaper on the commandline
- using Natural Earth Data
- want to use filter to select only the a specific group of countries

There is a page with an example of selecting only a few counties from a state, this I adapted to:
`mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -filter '"NL,BE,CH".indexOf(iso_a2) > -1' -o format=svg out.svg`

I get:

> [filter] ReferenceError in expression [iso_a2==FR]: FR is not defined

Running the following, simplified command:
`mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -filter 'iso_a2=="FR"' -o format=svg out.svg`

I still get:

> [filter] ReferenceError in expression [iso_a2==FR]: FR is not defined

Anyone out there with the tip to get me started in the Mapshaper game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try (tested)

```bsh
mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -filter "WB_A2=='FR'" -o format=svg out.svg
```

or for multiple values

```bsh
mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -filter '"NL,BE,CH".indexOf(WB_A2) > -1' -o format=svg out.svg
# Either
mapshaper ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp -filter "['NL','BE','CH'].indexOf(WB_A2) > -1" -o format=svg out.svg
```

Why because there is no `iso_a2` but an `ISO_A2`. Moreover, it value is `-99` for France e.g below screen capture so you have to use another filter to get the SVG you want (what I've done)
You also need to quote the value because `-filter` option value use JavaScript syntax and a string need to be quoted with JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I found out that I'm using a rather old version of the Natural Earth Data. And I think it's very good to know to select the column name first.